# Proof of decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, monotone-functions

> Can someone help me prove that the sequence
>
> $$\left(1+\frac{1}{N} \right)^{N+1}$$
>
> is decreasing for $N \in \Bbb N $?

EDIT: I have tried the following..

\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{K}\right)^{K+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{K+1}\right)^{K+1}}
     & =\left(1+\frac{1}{K^{2}+2K}\right)^{K+1} \\
\tag{Bernoulli}
     & >1+\frac{K+1}{K^{2}+2K} \\
  & >1+\frac{K+1}{K^{2}+2K+1} \\
  & =1+\frac{1}{K+1} \\
  & =\frac{K+2}{K+1} \\
\end{align}

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{K+1}\right)^{K+2}=\frac{K+2}{K+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{K+1}\right)^{K+1}<\left(1+\frac{1}{K+1}\right)^{K+1}$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Among other things, that lets us focus our answers on the issue that has you hung up.

Comment: Please update your original post. That is unreadable.